# Strange Error in Chrome Console - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: html, google-chrome, amazon-s3, html5-video

I'm using HTML5 background video on a webpage which is set to loop. The video content is loaded from Amazon S3 it plays fine in chrome on when the page loads but stops playing after it has looped. After the first loop it throws the 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED' error in the console referencing the .webm video that is supposed to loop.

It loops fine in Firefox but doesn't load at all in Safari.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Comment: Same here.  Ever find an answer?

Comment: It's weird that no one answer this question.

Comment: Had the same error with static files. You can try the advice given here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/SFLJGabwaK0 (clear browser data - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en)